# How to catch the successful request using httpClient interceptor?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

The most of the httpClient interceptor tutorials are catching the errors response in order to show an alert.

Examples:

https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-http-interceptor/

https://medium.com/@deniscangemi/intercept-http-requests-in-angular-c6392b7b0e0

It possible to present a loader for each HTTP request using the interceptor?

If yes, How to handle or catch the successful HTTP request in order to dismiss the loader.

Comment: The example in the first link you posted contains a comment that states: "`Intercepts all HTTP requests`"

Comment: If my question is not clear ask for clarifying instead of downvoting! I know it for all HTTP requests and it's a good example. But my question if no error occurred where you will catch the successful response?

Comment: Change it from `catchError` to `tap`, and it will execute for the successful requests

Comment: It possible to add it both @user184994

Comment: Yep, just do one after the other, comma separated within the `pipe` function, like  `pipe(tap(...), catchError(...))`

Comment: I got an error `Cannot find  name 'tap'`

Comment: You need to import it: `import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: Ok Thank you, Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `tap` function inside the pipe as well, which will execute for every run, like so:

```
            import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

            // ...

            return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
                tap(data => {
                  // Do your success stuff in here
                }),
                catchError(error => {
                  // Do your error handling in here
                })
            );
```

Comment: You should clarify that tap only runs on successful requests, on error cases tap will be skipped and catch error will be executed. I think you meant that but "on every request" would be interpreted otherwise.

Comment: For some how the tap is called twice! Any reason for this?

Comment: It will be called each time `handle` emits a value

Comment: It's calling twice only for the first load

Comment: is `data` the response in the `tap` function? I want to try to pass `data` to another function that takes an `HttpResponse` as a parameter but Angular keeps complaining that `data` is type `Object` and can't be applied @user184994

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple service, which allows me to enable/disable loaders across my entire application. You just have to provide a unique name for an API call:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class WatcherService {
    private watchers = new Map<String, Boolean>();

    public isLoading(watcher: String): Boolean {
        return this.watchers.get(watcher) || false;
    }

    public start(watcher: String) {
        this.watchers.set(watcher, true);
    }

    public stop(watcher: String) {
        this.watchers.set(watcher, false);
    }
}
```

The key may be, for example, API endpoint URL. You can inject the watcher into the interceptor.

This way you can display loaders anywhere, without worring about passing flags/events between many layers of components, just to show a loader.

For example, I have a listing in my application. I can fetch new items for the listing from many places (filters, searchbar or after user scrolls down). I don't have to connect all the components to my listing to display the loader, I just have to call:

`watcher.start('actionName')`

and the listing knows, that it should display the loader:

`<qlisting [loading]="watcher.isLoading(getUnitsActionName)">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and verify if there is any error in your response.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
    
    
    export class HttpInterceptorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
            
              constructor() { }
            
              intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
            
                return next.handle(request).pipe(
                  map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                      if (event.ok) {
                         console.log('Success');
                      } else {
                        console.log('Error');
                      }
                    }
            
                    return event;
                  })
                );
              }
            }
```

Solution 2 :
Using catchError .

```
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import {
      HttpEvent,
      HttpHandler,
      HttpInterceptor,
      HttpRequest,
      HttpResponse
    } from '@angular/common/http';
        
        
        export class HttpInterceptorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
                
                  constructor() { }
                
                  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
                
                    return next.handle(request).pipe(
                      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                          if (event.ok) {
                             console.log('Success');
                          } else {
                            console.log('Error');
                          }
                        }
                
                        return event;
                      }),catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                            let errorMsg = '';
                            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                                errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
                                console.log('This is client side error');
                            } else {
                                errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
                                console.log('This is server side error');
                            }
                            console.log(errorMsg);
                            return throwError(() => errorMsg);
                       })
                    );
                  }
                }
```